# Is there a way to auto-update a live OS?

Tags: upgrade, live-usb, software-updates, livecd, persistence

I'm currently using a Debian installation for a DIY router. In the interests of security, I'm wondering how I might switch to a non-persistent installation in order to defend against any persistence gained after an exploit against the system (BIOS attacks not in scope).

I'm thinking about using a pre-configured live USB. I'd have persistent storage (in the form of a USB) to store rules, configuration, etc. But of course with the core system being read-only I wouldn't be receiving important security updates, so then an attacker would just be able to keep exploiting the system instead of gaining persistence.

I want to keep it low-maintenence - I don't want to keep having to look whether there's been a CVE in anything and 'recompile' my live USB each time.

A possbility might be a PXE boot from a seperate system which auto-updates the live OS and packages, but then there's the chicken and the egg because if the router goes offline it can't update.

Wondering if anyone has any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure "non persistent" and "updates" are mutually exclusive. You could have an overlayfs that keeps track of file changes in your persistent storage, but it would end up being equivalent to simply installing a normal OS onto the flash drive, which defeats your purpose.

Comment: yeah, what you describe is a paradox. Also, I think you'll find that "non-persistent" doesn't mean much for a router, as these kinds of devices usually are power-cycled maybe once a month to once a year. And whatever was able to take over your router once will also be able to do it once more. Especially in botnets, re-infection is a mechanism already built in.